# Docstring convention for tuple parameter?

Tags: python

How should a tuple parameter be documented? Should it specify the types inside the tuple or just the fact that it's a tuple? What's a good way to document it?

```
def generate_dependency_table(head_revision, dependencies):
    """
    Generate a dependency table as a bytes object.

    Parameters:
    dependencies ?

    Returns:
    dependency_table (bytes): The generated dependency table.
    """
```

Comment: `typing.Tuple[type1, type2, ...]`

Comment: What does "typing." before Tuple represent?

Comment: Python type hints are put in variable annotations, not docstrings.

Comment: It's the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module.

Comment: I updated it to show what my docstring looks like. Do you mind updating it to show what it's suppose to look like? "dependencies" is a tuple containing a dependency (str) and a resource_type (int).

Answer (score 0):

Use type hints, not a docstring, to annotate function parameter types.

```
from typing import Tuple

def generate_dependency_table(head_revision: int, dependencies: Tuple[str, int]) -> bytes:
```

Comment: It says invalid syntax?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.8.

Comment: Actually, I got it to work by moving the : to after bytes. Also, what would a list of tuples look like?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that

Comment: `List[Tuple[str, int]]`

Comment: I gave you a link to the typing documentation.

Comment: I have one last question if you don't mind. What about a named tuple? Is this just the same as a tuple, or is it any different?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

Comment: I mean a named tuple as an argument, not the type hint for the named tuple.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're making.

Comment: Tuple[str, int] but it's a named tuple. Do I specify the names?

Comment: As it says in the documentation: *These are not used in annotations. They are building blocks for declaring types.*